# WPF: Resize the window to a button size

Tags: wpf, resize, wpf-controls, toolbar

i want to be able to resize the whole window to a first button size on that button click. And restore it's original size on next click. I hope that there are some implementations of this kind of functionality, but didn't find it yet.
Could someone share an example or describe the plan how to manage it nicely.

I thought that i should dinamicaly create all other subcontrols and remove them from the grid on button click, to be able to shrink window size to first button only.
Or maybe i can move all controls under the first button and make them invisible, so that only one that button was shown.
Thanks a lot.

[window prototype]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how this can be achieved, Good luck!

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="Window1" x:Class="WPF_Tester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Tester"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50,50,0,0" Content="Window 1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPF_Tester
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WinOriginalWidth = Window1.Width;
        WinOriginalHeight = Window1.Height;
    }

    double WinOriginalWidth;
    double WinOriginalHeight;
    bool SizeCheck = false;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (SizeCheck == false)
        {
            Window1.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
            SizeCheck = true;
        }
        else if(SizeCheck == true)
        {
            Window1.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
            Window1.Width = WinOriginalWidth;
            Window1.Height = WinOriginalHeight;
            SizeCheck = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Eh, after WinForms, i thought i would be a bit harder task, this things helped me:

```
window = new Window {
                                 SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
                                 ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip,
                                 Content = AromaPanelModel.Model.View,
                                 WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                            };
        // in a User Control
        private void btnResize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow.Width = _panelFolded ? _initialWidth : btnResize.Width + 12;
            _panelFolded = !_panelFolded;
            btnResize.Content = _panelFolded ? ">>" : "<<";
        }
```

Comment: But problem is that from the start button doesn't work, but if you do any resize with mouse - then button starts work, i wonder - what is a problem...